# Scraping hidden value in link

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am scraping the contents of a website.

I noticed that the field that I want to scrape does not contain the exact information that I need. User needs to click it to reveal the correct value

e.g.
In screen, user can see "Send Email". Upon clicking the Send Email, it will change to support@company.com.

Now, I want to scrape "support@company.com".

One strategy that worked is parse the node of the link. I used `string.IndexOf` and `string.Substring`)

```
<a href="#" onclick="displayEmail(this, 'support@company.com');......>Send Email</a>
```

Are there any other options?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use regular expressions to check for the specified pattern.

Comment: @subzero Can you give a sample code please? What if i need to scrape a name or number instead of email?

Answer (score 0):

To find a specific node or get a node's attribute value from HTML document (or fragment) you could use AgilityPack. Further, to extract a specific information from the string you could use regular expressions, string functions etc. It depends on the kind of information you want to extract.

To scrape email address, or just numbers I'd use regular expression (e.g. from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)).

Here is an example on how to scrape email address from the HTML fragment you provided:

```
var regex = new Regex(
    @"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
var html = @"<a href='#' onclick='displayEmail(this, ""support@company.com"")'>Send Email</a>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

// just an example on how to get node's attribute value
// your selectors could be completely different
var onclick = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("a").Attributes["onclick"].Value;
var email = regex.Match(onclick);
```